# Yii2 renderPartial/renderAjax does not load the js on the view

Tags: ajax, yii2

When I render a view via the renderAjax or the renderPartial methods from the controller the js added to the view don't work. I've got a google places autocomplete and a custom event handler on a form button.

Comment: no one can suggest you a proper solution until unless you add the code you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between renderPartial() and render() ist just that render() applies a layout and renderPartial() does not.

A partial test.php containing

```
<script>
   console.log("test!");
</script>
```

should output `test!` to the console when rendered like

```
public function actionIndex() {
   return $this->renderPartial('test');
}
```

Did you test that? Are there Errors written to the console?